# Bureau of Labor Statistics Query Geographic Profile Not Working

Tags: labor

https://www.bls.gov/help/hlpforma.htm#GP

The above link is supposed to provide the formatting details for the series ID for "geographic profiles". The example series Id they provide is: "GPU00200000R0328".

However, upon trying to query for that particular series ID in the BLS data query tool:

https://beta.bls.gov/dataQuery/search

No results come up.

What gives? Is this feature to be released? Am I doing something wrong?